# Forwarding the request from one jsp to another jsp with all request parameters?

Tags: java, jsp, web-applications

i have this scenario. User enter some stuff on jsp form in browser and submit. In servlet i process the request and show the jsp page1 to client which has just continue
button. Now on click of continue, i want to forward this request to another jsp page2 with all request parameter present on page1. basically i want to get all request parameters which were present in first request on page 2 also? I am not getting how should i go
for this? I dont think i can use jsp forward as per my understanding it would work only when both when we want to forward from jsp (on server side) not on client side?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two ways to implement that:

- output all parameters in hidden fields, and submit them in the 2nd request
- store everything in the session

Comment: question on first point, if i have customer info object in request, how will submit it as hidden field. I will get customer object as string in second jsp. Right? regarding session, my second legacy jsp also expects from request. Bad trick is before forwarding it to second jsp, i get values from session  object and put back in request object?

Answer (score 1):

Following are a pair of ways to achieve this

1. Put the information in session object in first request and access it from session object in second.
2. On the intermediate page displayed, have hidden form elements which will carry the values and send it back on continuing.

Comment: Sorry for duplicate answer, Seems I was late by few seconds :)

Comment: question on second point, if i have customer info object in request, how will submit it as hidden field. I will get customer object as string in second jsp. Right? regarding session, my second legacy jsp also expects values from request. Bad trick is before forwarding it to second jsp, i get values from session object and put back in request object?

Comment: If second JSP is not in your control then second approach makes sense. If second JSP expects values from request, then you need to pass them in a from or in URL as the jsp expects.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Servlet Forward to pass all request parameters to another JSP or Servlet:

```
getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/yourJSP.jsp").forward(request, response);
```

Servlet forward will forward the existing request to another JSP or Servlet, so all the request parameters and attributes will be available to the destination JSP or Servlet (The reason you can use the Servlet forward is that JSP is also a Servlet after translation).

You may find following resources useful:

[Pass data from servlet to jsp](https://www.programmergate.com/pass-data-servlet-jsp/)

[Servlet Redirect vs Forward](http://www.mysamplecode.com/2011/06/java-servlet-redirect-vs-forward.html)