# how to pass and retrieve the value object   while making them hidden field?

Tags: java, web-applications, servlets

This question is in continuation of [Forwarding the request from one jsp to another jsp with all request parameters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10121877/forwarding-the-request-from-one-jsp-to-another-jsp-with-all-request-parameters). For the convenience of user, will explain the scenario  and new query on that .

i have this scenario. User enter some stuff on jsp form in browser and submit. In servlet i process the request and show the jsp page1 to client which has just continue button. Now on click of continue, i want to forward this request to another jsp page2 with all request parameter present on page1. basically i want to get all request parameters which were present in first request on page 2 also. As per replies i can go for hidden variable which i agree. Now a question this.

**EDIT**

**if i have customer info object in request, how will submit it as hidden field. I will get customer object as string in second jsp. Right? Is there a way i can get it as customer object in request instead of string object?**

Comment: Just like the answer from previous one,if you want to pass an object you should pass it using Session...

Comment: You have asked the same question. But in different manner. Its duplicate. Answer has been given in your previous question.

Comment: Regarding this question, actually i am concerned with edited part . I agree previous question has been answered.

Answer (score -1):

Store it in Session scope and retrieve where ever u want to get it back, on the first call of servlet , just put it in session and later on third jsp just get it from the session